# How to override the write method in res.users class

Tags: overriding, odoo-10, odoo

I want to inherit the res.users class and override her write method, so I wrote this code:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    is_commercial = fields.Boolean(string= 'is Commercial')

    @api.multi
    def write(self, values):
        super(User, self).write()
        for partner in self.partner_id:
            partner.is_commercial = self.is_commercial
```

and I created this res.partner class too:

```py
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    is_commercial = fields.Boolean(string= 'is Commercial')
```

Now when I try to change the is_commercial content it appears this error:

```
TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

It appears to me that there's a syntaxe error in overriding the write method in res.users class. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: replace `super(User, self).write()` with `super(User, self).write(values)`. That should work.

Comment: Also note that `self.partner_id` can raise another exception if `self` is not a singleton recordset.

Answer (score 1):

How to override the write method in res.users class: You just need to write this code to override the write method:

```
 class User(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'res.users'

  @api.multi
  def write(self, vals):
      res = super(User, self).write(vals)
            your code here...
      return res
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call write(), you should pass any argument or context. So you can pass values in write() method. Like below

```
super(User, self).write(values)
```

because write() take dictionary type data.

Answer (score 0):

When you call write(), try passing any argument or context.

For example:

```
@api.multi
def action_cancel(self):
    res = super(SaleOrder, self).action_cancel()
    .
    .
    your logic
    .
    .
    return res
```